# (Easy) Matlab: finding zero spots (fzero)

Tags: function, matlab

I'm all new to Matlab and I'm supposed to use this function to find all 3 zero spots.

f.m (my file where the function can be found)

```
function fval = f(x)
% FVAL = F(X), compute the value of a test function in x
fval = exp(-x) - exp(-2*x) + 0.05*x - 0.25;
```

So obviously I write "type f" to read my function but then I try to do like fzero ('f', 0) and I get the ans 0.4347 and I assume that's 1 of my 3 zero spots but how to find the other 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [fzero documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html)

> `x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a zero of fun near `x0`, if `x0` is a scalar. `fun` is a function handle. The value `x` returned by fzero is near a point where fun changes sign, or NaN if the search fails. In this case, the search terminates when the search interval is expanded until an Inf, NaN, or complex value is found.

So it can't find all zeros by itself, only one! Which one depends on your inputted `x0`.

Here's an example of how to find some more zeros, if you know the interval. However it just repeatedly calls `fzero` for different points in the interval (and then still can miss a zero if your discretization is to coarse), a more clever technique will obviously be faster:

http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-19BT9/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-19BT9

As you can see in the documentation and the example above, the proper way for calling fzero is with a function handle (`@fun`), so in your case:

```
zero1 = fzero(@f, 0);
```

From [this info](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-x%29+-+exp%28-2%2ax%29+%2B+0.05%2ax+-+0.25%3B) you can also see that the actual roots are at `0.434738`, `1.47755` and `4.84368`. So if you call fzero with 0.4, 1.5 and 4.8 you probably get those values out of it (convergence of fzero depends on which algorithm it uses and what function you feed it).

Comment: Well so what do you mean I should write? The first I did was correct? "fzero ('f',0)" and to find the rest I just swap the zero for a "1" and a "2"?

Comment: I don't think you have to write it like `type f` and then `fzero('f',0)` but like `fzero(@f,0)`. About using other `x0` for calling fzero with: yes, if you swap the 0 for a 1 or 2, you could get different results, depending on where the actual zeros are.

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what you mean, If I do fzero(@f,0) I get the answer: 0.4347 which is 1 zero place but I need to find the rest 3. According to my exercise there's 3 zero spots and I've found 1 so far. How do I write to find all of them?

Comment: Oh I see, so if I type, zero1 = fzero(@f, 0); I get 0.4347 and if I change the 0 to a 2, I get the 2nd zero spot and if I change the 2 to a 4 I get the third zero spot. That's all good, but how come it skips some of the numbers? Like 1 and 3

Comment: it takes the value you give as a initial guess to go look for a root, it's not that you get the 1st root if you input 1 and the 2nd root if you input 2 !!! Read through (the summary of) [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) for more info!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement Gunther Struyf's answer: there's a nice function on the file exchange by Stephen Morris called [FindRealRoots](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15122-real-roots-on-interval). This function finds an approximation to all roots of any function on any interval.

It works by approximating the function with a Chebyshev polynomial, and then compute the roots of that polynomial. This obviously only works well with continuous, smooth and otherwise well-behaved functions, but the function you give seems to have those qualities.

You would use this something like so:

```
%# find approximate roots
R = FindRealRoots(@f, -1, 10, 100);

%# refine all roots thus found
for ii = 1:numel(R)
    R(ii) = fzero(@f, R(ii)); end
```